# Is there a term for people pooling money to invest it?

Tags: meaning

is there a term for a group of 15 persons, which collecting small amount of  money every month from each one of the group to open small business  ?

Comment: We would call them _partners_ or _investors,_ There are many other possible terms as well. We might call them a _pool of investors._

Comment: Looking up [pool](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/pool) in a thesaurus gives [syndicate](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/syndicate), which gives [company](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/company), which gives [partnership](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/partnership), which hints at "cooperative" and "association" and "society".

Answer (score 1):

An

> **investor**

is a person who supplies *capital* (*money*) to make more *capital*.

A group of investors can be called a

> **pool** of investors

A

> **partnership**
>   **syndicate**

is a type of *pool* where each member of the group shares in the *profits* and *losses* of an *investment*

there are different *types* of *partnerships* which can have differing laws governing them such as

> **cooperatives**
>   **associations**
>   **societies**